# If $G = H \cup K \cup L$, then $[G:H] = [G:K] = [G:L]=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a problem from Isaacs's *Algebra*. Let $G$ be a finite group and $H, K, L$ be proper subgroups of $G$ such that $G= H \cup K \cup L$. He asks us to show that, in this case, $[G:H] = [G:K] = [G:L] =2$.

It seems simple enough, but I can't get started on it! Any *hint* would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the result is true then there can never exist $H, K\lneq G$ such that $G=H\cup K$. It seems to me that a nice place to start would be to try to work out why $G\neq H\cup K$.

Comment: @user1729 - can you elaborate why the result implies that there can never exist $H, K < G$ with $G = H \cup K$?

Comment: If $G=H\cup K$ then take $L=\{1\}$. (If $L=\{1\}$ has index two then $G$ has order two and $H=K=L=\{1\}$, so $G\neq H\cup K\cup L$.)

Comment: @user1729 Ah, I see it now: since $H, K$ are not subgroups of one another, there must be $a, b$ such that $ab \not \in H$ and $ab \not \in K$, so $G \not = H cup K$.

Comment: @Nagase: If you don't want to go look at the solution in the duplicate: start by showing that if $G=H\cup K\cup L$, then $H\cap K=H\cap L = K\cap L= H\cap K\cap L$, and that for any one of the subgroups, if $x,y$ are neither in the subgroup, then their product *is*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Many thanks for the tip! Already working on it